# convert the JQuery code to "Vanilla" JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to push my JS knowledge, hence I am trying to convert JQuery code to JavaScript. In this I am not getting where to call x function(){which is in comment}. Want to add the tooltip to JavaScript instead of JQuery. I try my level best to convert that JQuery code to "vanilla" JS but did some mistakes. Can you please tell me where I went wrong??

```js
var persons = [{
  firstname: "Malcom",
  lastname: "Reynolds",
  id: 1
}, {
  firstname: "Kaylee",
  lastname: "Frye",
  id: 2
}, {
  firstname: "Jayne",
  lastname: "Cobb",
  id: 3
}, {
  firstname: "Mal",
  lastname: "Rlds",
  id: 4
}, {
  firstname: "ylee",
  lastname: "ye",
  id: 5
}, {
  firstname: "yne",
  lastname: "Cb",
  id: 6
}, {
  firstname: "Mal",
  lastname: "Rolds",
  id: 7
}, {
  firstname: "lee",
  lastname: "Fryedwwwwd",
  id: 8
}, {
  firstname: "Jay",
  lastname: "bdwe",
  id: 9
}, {
  firstname: "Maljh",
  lastname: "Rolds",
  id: 10
}, {
  firstname: "ljyyu",
  lastname: "jhjFryed",
  id: 11
}, {
  firstname: "ryJay",
  lastname: "jkmCdwe",
  id: 12
}, {
  firstname: "yuryMal",
  lastname: "jhkhRolds",
  id: 13
}, {
  firstname: "rtulee",
  lastname: "Frwwd",
  id: 14
}, {
  firstname: "ryuyJay",
  lastname: "Cryyobbdwe",
  id: 15
}];

var start = 1;
var size = 5;
var current = 0;

function getFullName(item, index) {
  return "<li>" + item.firstname + "<span class='tool-tip'>" + item.lastname + "</span> " + item.id + "</li>";
}

var getFullNameForHighlighting = function(searchText) {
    return function(item, index) {
       var index = item.firstname.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchText.toUpperCase())+searchText.length;
       console.log(index)
           return "<li>" + "<span class='highlight'>"+searchText + "</span>" +item.firstname.substring(index) + "<span class='tool-tip'>" + item.lastname + "</span> " + item.id + "</li>";
    }
};

function myFunction1(){
  current = size;
  document.getElementById("myUL").innerHTML = persons.map(getFullName).slice(start, current).join('');
}

function myFunction() {
  current = size;
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, count = 0;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();

  var longWords = persons.filter(function(person) {

    return person.firstname.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1
  });
  var message = "Result:" + longWords.length + " words containing '" + input.value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = message;

  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  varInnerHtmlText = longWords.map(getFullNameForHighlighting(filter));
  ul.innerHTML = varInnerHtmlText;
 
  highlight();
}

function highlight() {

  var inputText, filter1, innerHTML, index;
  inputText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  console.log(inputText);
  filter1 = inputText.value.toUpperCase();
  console.log(filter1);
  innerHTML1 = inputText.innerHTML;
  var ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  console.log(innerHTML1);
  index = innerHTML1.indexOf(filter1);
  
  if (index >= 0) {
    innerHTML1 = innerHTML1.substring(0, index) + "<span class='highlight'>" + innerHTML1.substring(index, index + filter1.length) + "</span>" + innerHTML1.substring(index + filter1.length);
    filter1.innerHTML = innerHTML1;
  }
}
var x = 0;
function myFunction3(e) {
  console.log(e);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ++x; 
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#clear {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px;
  /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 550px;
}

.left {
  width: 20%;
}

.right {
  width: 60%;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

ul.demo {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

ul.demo li {
  position: right;
}

.tool-tip {
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  color: black;
}

.highlight {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

li em {
  background: #ff6;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.jscroll.js"></script>
<script src="two.js"></script>



<body onload="myFunction1()">
  <br>
  <br>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column left" style="background-color:White;"></div>

    <div class="column right" style="background-color:#bbb;">
      <form id="myForm" onsubmit='return onSubmit(this)'>

        Find:
        <input type="text" class="demo1" id="myInput" align="center" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search here...">

        <button id="clear" onclick="document.getElementById('myInput').value = ''"> Clear </button>

      </form>
      <br>
      <ul id="demo">
        15 words total
      </ul>
      <br>
      <div onscroll="myFunction3(this)" style="width:100%;height:250px;overflow:scroll;padding:5px;color:#714D03;scrollbar-base-color:#DEBB07;">

        <ul id="myUL" class="demo">

        </ul>
      </div>
       <p><span id="demo"></span></p> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    $('#myUL').on("mouseenter", "li", function() {
      $(this).find("span").show();
    })

    $('#myUL').on("mouseout", "li", function() {
      $(this).find("span").hide();
    })

  </script>

  <script>
//   function x()
//   {
//       var ul = document.getElementById("myUL").getElementsByTagName('li');
//       console.log(ul);

//       ul.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
//    if ( e.target.matchesSelector('myUL li') ) {
//         return "<li>" + item.firstname + "<span class='tool-tip'>" + item.lastname + "</span> " + item.id + "</li>";
//    }
// }, false);

//       ul.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
//    if ( e.target.matchesSelector('myUL li') ) {
//       return "<li>" + item.firstname + item.id + "</li>";
//    }
// }, false);
//   }

  </script>
```

Comment: Post your attempted code in the question, and explain where your attempts are going wrong (what error messages are you getting, what's not working?). Also, read both the "*[mcve]*" and "*[ask]*" guidelines.

Comment: This is just jQuery code.  There is no evidence you tried to solve this for yourself.  Post your entire, working example code and show your work, please.

Comment: This is not trying.. This is trying to let the guys on the internet do the work for you.

Comment: To everyone freaking out, OP said in the question where his attempt was: on JSFiddle, in the commented block. Yeah, it should have been posted in the question, but at least put in the effort to read the question before you complain that the asker didn't put in any effort.

Answer (score 2):

To do this in native JS you can use `querySelectorAll()` to  find the elements, then `addEventListener()` to add the event handlers. Also note that `mouseleave` is a much better event to use here, as it will avoid some of the flickering issues you may encounter when showing a child element under a `mouseout` event. Try this:

```js
var liCollection = document.querySelectorAll('#myUL li');
[].forEach.call(liCollection, function(li) {
  li.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    this.querySelector('span').style.display = 'inline';
  });
  li.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    this.querySelector('span').style.display = 'none';
  });  
})
```

```css
span { display: none; }
```

```html
<ul id="myUL">
  <li>Foo <span>bar</span></li>
  <li>Lorem <span>impsum</span></li>   
<ul>
```

With that being said, **CSS is a far more appropriate and better solution here**:

```css
li span { display: none; }
li:hover span { display: inline; }
```

```html
<ul id="myUL">
  <li>Foo <span>bar</span></li>
  <li>Lorem <span>impsum</span></li>   
<ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Rory...!!!